# Color some areas delimited programmatically

Tags: colors, bitmap, drawing

I want to write an algorithm that allows me to fill color in delimited area in a draw. I show you an example:

BEFORE
[image]

AFTER

[image]

what's the way to begin this algorithm? Where I can act to realize this function?
Or is there something done?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill comes to mind, but I don't think this is the best answer...

Also note, if you zoom into your image with microsoft paint, or other imaging software, you may notice that there are blurs that make this technique more tricky, ideally this technique works with cleaner sharp pixel borders.

most shape drawing subroutines allow filled shapes by default, but what you are asking is a bit more tricky.

In particular, I would normally draw a filled shape, then draw an unfilled shape identical to the filled shape, but with a different color for border, simulating what you want to do.

the pseudocode for what I mean is

```
 setcolor(backgroundcolor); 
 fillrect(0, 0, width, height);

 setcolor(roofcolor); 
 filltriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
 setcolor(black); 
 drawtriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

 ... so on
```